# How can I make something that is fast for the server to compute, but slow for the client to compute?

Tags: security, cryptography

Something that would take the server a few milliseconds or less to compute, and take the client a few hundred milliseconds?

The server would create a challenge, send it to the client, the client would compute the answer and send it to the server, then the server would verify the answer.

UPDATE: Why? The server has a function that uses significant processing power.  I don't want a client to be able to maliciously overload the server by simply sending 100s of requests per second to this function. By requiring an answer to the challenge, an attacker can only send requests as fast as they can compute the answers.

Comment: Tell us more about what you are trying to do and maybe we can help you.  There are a number of ways that I can think of to do what you are saying, but I don't know which ones would apply.

Comment: Don't you think there are... more straightforward ways to limit the requests? Plain old DoS attacks should be simle to avert, DDoS is harder but there are propably still easier solutions.

Comment: You can counteract a simple DoS attack, but you can't overpower a DDoS this way. You need to look for some kind of authentication before the client is allowed to use the computation-intensive functions of the server.

Comment: @delnan - Maybe. I'm not sure how complicated what I'm asking would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by saying I think you are headed down the wrong road.

With that said, one way to do what you are describing would be to put together a simple puzzle that is brute forcible by the receiving end.  For instance, you could send the hash of a 3 or 4 character password (solved reasonably quickly), the client is required to figure out the password (by brute force) and send it back (possibly encrypted with a pre-shared key if you are trying to authenticate).

Please understand that this will not prevent anyone from maliciously overloading the server.  A malicious attacker can still just disconnect once they've received the puzzle (without solving it) and connect again.  If the attack is distributed, it gets even worse.

EDIT:

@Nick Johnson is right.  You want to also include a random salt to prevent precomputation attacks.  Send the salt along with the hash.  It gets concatenated with each password that the client tries.

Comment: Factorising a number would be more conventional. But as you say the client can disconnect, after the server has done its computation but before the client has to do its. Perhaps there's problems, such as first number with two relatively factors, that can be just roughly checked by the server.

Comment: Thanks! The hash idea is perfect.  I'll take your suggestion about going down the wrong road into consideration too.

Comment: @Luke: The idea is more sound than you give it credit for.  The server won't perform the costly calcuation until it recieves a valid response to the proof-of-work challenge.  (The idea is that it is not the connection itself that is costly, but some subsequent operation that is performed on behalf of the client).

Comment: @caf That prevents a DoS of the processor intensive task, but not a DDoS.  If it takes 1 machine 1 second to solve the puzzle, how long does it take 80000 machines to solve 80000 puzzles?  1 second.  Thus with 80000 machines I can send 80000 requests in 1 second.  What you really want is some form of authentication here.  Even a single shared account or pre-shared key would be better.

Comment: @Luke: Reducing the DoS threat from "anyone with 1 machine" to "anyone with an 80,000 host botnet" still sounds like a partial win to me ;)

Comment: @caf It's definitely a partial win.  And maybe it's good enough for the OP.  We don't really know his full set of requirements.  If it works for him, then great.

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking for is called a "proof of work". Here's a really simple one:

1. The server generates a random nonce, `n`, and picks a number of bits, `b`, and sends both to the client.
2. The client calculates `h = sha1(n + x)`, where `x` is an arbitrary suffix, and `h` ends with `b` '0' bits.
3. The client sends `x` back to the server as a proof-of-work.

This works because predicting the output of a secure hash function is difficult, so your only option is brute force. If the server asks for one with `b` trailing 0s, one average one in `2^b` hashes will meet that criteria, meaning they will have to do on average `O(2^(b-1))` work.

One caveat to this approach: If you're dealing with a web client, you need to make the proof of work easy enough that it's doable quickly in Javascript. But javascript is slow compared to native code, and your attacker will be able to write native code to compute the proof of work much faster - so he has a substantial advantage over your legitimate clients.

The standard alternative, as unpleasant as it is, is to require a CAPTCHA.

Comment: This is a good, standard method for a proof-of-work, because it relies on a standard security property of the underlying primitive (in this case, the preimage resistance of the hash function).  Note of course that `n` must be sufficiently long to prevent creation of a dictionary - at least 128 bits).